# How to set SQL to find records from last sunday to this sunday (1 week)

Tags: mysql, sql, date, intervals

This is similar to what I have now, which is:

`` SELECT COUNT(author) FROM `posts` WHERE `date` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND author='FooBar' ``

This will give me a count of how many times an author has posted in the past 1 week.

I want to instead have it so if I am to run the program on Sunday at 5:30 PM to look for posts from last Sunday 12:00 AM to this Sunday 12:00 AM. Likewise, if I forget to run it on Sunday and it's monday now. I still want it to run from last Sunday 12:00 AM to the Sunday that just past 12:00 AM

Edit:

I have done what I needed using PHP to form the correct SQL statement, but I am still curious how to do this in just SQL.

```
<?php
    $dayofweek = strftime("%A",time());
    if($dayofweek == "Sunday") {
        $last_sunday = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime('Last Sunday'));
        $this_sunday = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime('Sunday'));
    } else {
        $last_sunday = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime('Last Sunday',strtotime('Last Sunday')));
        $this_sunday = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime('Last Sunday'));
    }
    print "last_sunday={$last_sunday}<br>";
    print "this_sunday={$this_sunday}<br>";
    print "SELECT COUNT(author) FROM `posts` WHERE `date` <= '$this_sunday' AND `date` >= '$last_sunday' AND author='FooBar'";
?>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To get the latest preceding sunday midnight, this should do it. Replace both instances of `NOW()` with your datetime to check another date.

```sql
SELECT DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1 DAY) latest_sun
```

To get the sunday one week earlier, instead use `DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+6 DAY`.

EDIT: That'd make your query;

```
SELECT COUNT(author)
FROM `posts` 
WHERE author='FooBar'
  AND `date` >= DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+6 DAY)
  AND `date` <  DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1 DAY)
```

Comment: How do I incorporate those into variables I can use in the SQL, specifically mysql? and will it work the day I run it is sunday

Comment: @BHare Added the complete query, and yes, it'll find the latest midnight to sunday, which for example means if it's run between Jul 21 12am 2013 and Jul 27 23:59:59, it'll find data between Jul 14 12am and the end of Jul 20.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Thanks your answer solved my problem, but I am unable to understand this part: `DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1 DAY)` how perfectly this part get last Sunday?

Comment: @SagarGuhe `DAYOFWEEK` returns 1 for sunday, 2 for monday and so on. The query subtracts 1 from that value which makes 0 for sunday, 1 for monday and so on. It then subtracts that many days from todays date to find last sunday (if it's sunday already, it'll then subtract 0 days, if it's monday subtract 1 day etc) Make sense?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Now perfectly understood, Thanks for your explanation, surprised and appreciate your lightning fast response :)