# Query to get all the data prior to 2 weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can you please help me with the query to retrieve the defect data whose creation date is prior to 2 weeks. I know the below query can help me get the data.

```
select Defect_ID, Assigned_to, created_DATE 
from BUG
where created_DATE < dateadd(week,-2,getdate());
```

But the tricky part here is when i say 2 weeks prior what i mean is, say today is a monday 25th Jan and i need the data 2 weeks prior to today, i need the data prior to 18th Jan. What i mean here is that the present week has data for just 25th Jan and the previous week has data for 18th Jan to 24th Jan. So when i say 2 weeks prior i dont mean exactly 14 days but the data for the days excluding the present week and the previous week.

So I need a query that will work for any day of the week and give me the data excluding the present week and the previous week. Week endind is always a Sunday.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set SQL to find records from last sunday to this sunday (1 week)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912871/how-to-set-sql-to-find-records-from-last-sunday-to-this-sunday-1-week)

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract the day of the week and then subtract 1 week:

```
select Defect_ID, Assigned_to, created_DATE 
from BUG
where created_DATE < dateadd(day, - (7 + day(getdate())), getdate()) ;
```

This may not be exactly what you want, but it should put you on the right path.

Comment: Thanks for the this query. It really helped me think differently and get the answer i needed.

Answer (score 0):

> declare @datetoday date = '25-Jan-2016' -- or getdate()
>
> select Defect_ID, Assigned_to, created_DATE  from BUG where
>   created_DATE < dateadd(days,-14,@datetoday)

did not really understand your query but worth a try.