# Select data from last monday to sunday

Tags: mysql

How to select data from last monday to sunday. Like this

```
`WHERE
   `order`.order_createdAt >= date_sub(date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1 day), interval 1 month) 
and `order`.order_createdAt < date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1 day)`
```

this show data from last month
Upd. find this

```
`WHERE WEEK (order_createdAt) = WEEK( current_date)-1 
AND YEAR( order_createdAt) = YEAR( current_date );`
```

But it takes from past sunday to saturday

Comment: You mean the past Monday?

Comment: Provide some sample data or create your sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/  and ask for some expected output

Comment: @shmosel yes,the past monday

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422248/previous-monday-previous-sundays-date-based-on-todays-date

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912871/how-to-set-sql-to-find-records-from-last-sunday-to-this-sunday-1-week) might help you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check for `Last week Monday` to `This Sunday`, which is say Today's date is **`'2017-01-27'`** and **`Last week Monday`** date will be **`2017-01-16`** and **`This Sunday`** will be **`2017-01-22`**, then you can follow below query,

```
WHERE
   `order`.order_createdAt BETWEEN subdate(curdate(),dayofweek(curdate())+5)
and subdate(curdate(),dayofweek(curdate())-1)`
```

Hope this would help you out.

Comment: This is show data from past monday to saturday. Are you sure that this query will get same data tomorow?

Comment: It will get same data tomorrow too.

Answer (score 0):

Following SQL code might be useful to [Presto](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/) users who might be searching for same information in reference to same question asked, for data between **Last Monday** to **Next Sunday** ([an ISO week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)): -

```
WHERE date_column_ref BETWEEN date_add('day', dow(localtimestamp) * -1 + 1, localtimestamp) and date_add('day', 7 - dow(localtimestamp), localtimestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select subdate(curdate(), WEEKDAY(curdate()) + 7); # Monday
select subdate(curdate(), WEEKDAY(curdate()) + 1); # Sunday
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I been trying to search for the same issue on getting MONDAY to SUNDAY, from a specific day.

I have come-up with the following and hope this helps anyone who is looking for the same solution as I am.

The only issue I have is, I think this can be improved and open for suggestions as it's long.

```
SELECT 
    DATE_ADD(DATE('2021-05-30 02:12:43'),
        INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(DATE('2021-05-30 02:12:43')) DAY) AS MONDAY,
    DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE('2021-05-30 02:12:43'),
            INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(DATE('2021-05-30 02:12:43')) DAY),
        INTERVAL 6 DAY) AS SUNDAY
;
```

[image]